# How do i create a VB Macro that will save a certain file to all sub folders in a particular directory?

Tags: vba, file, ms-word, save

This is what I have so far, might be good might not haha!

I have been trying to save a word document to about 400+ folders without having to go through them all, can this be done through VB Macros? I got it working to just save it to the directory, but I cannot save it to all the Subfolders.

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String
Sub DoFolder(folder)
HostFolder = ("H:\test2")

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
      DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In folder.Files
      Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      ' Operate on each file
      ActiveDocument.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want 400+ copies of the same file?

Comment: its the same file sent out to 400 different clients, hence why it needs added to the folder for audit record purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommended reading: [Chip Pearson -Recursion And The FileSystemObject](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/recursionandfso.htm)

Make a recursive subroutine to iterate over all the subfolders (and their subfolders) in the root directory.

### `getAllSubfolderPaths`: returns an array that lists all the sub folders in a folder.

```
Function getAllSubfolderPaths(FolderPath As String, Optional FSO As Object, Optional List As Object)
    Dim fld As Object

    If FSO Is Nothing Then
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
        Set List = CreateObject("SYstem.Collections.ArrayList")
    End If

    List.Add FolderPath

    For Each fld In FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath).SubFolders
        getAllSubfolderPaths fld.Path, FSO, List
    Next

    getAllSubfolderPaths = List.ToArray
End Function
```

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Const RootFolder As String = "C:\Users\Owner\Pictures"
    Const SourcePath As String = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Youcam"
    Const SourceFileName As String = "Capture.PNG"

    Dim fld As Variant, FolderArray As Variant
    Dim Destination As String, Source As String

    FolderArray = getAllSubfolderPaths(RootFolder)

    For Each fld In FolderArray
        Destination = fld & "\" & SourceFileName
        Source = SourcePath & "\" & SourceFileName
        'Delete old copy of file
        If Destination <> Source And Len(Dir(Destination)) Then Kill Destination

        VBA.FileCopy Source:=Source, Destination:=Destination
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, when i run your code it crashes my word, i'm I doing anything wrong??

Comment: It's hard to say.  Did you use `Sub Test()` by modifying it's constants?

Comment: I did yes. Just keeps crashing word every time I run it.

Comment: @Tomlawson94 paste this in the Immediate Window `?Join(getAllSubfolderPaths("Insert Folder Path"), ",")` correct the path and press enter.  It should output a list of all the files to the Immediate Window.  Let me know if it works or it crashes Word.

Answer (score 2):

Gotta love auditing requirements...  You're basically on the right path, but you really only need one `FileSystemObject`. About the only errors I see are that you need the `.Path` of the folder here...

```
For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
  DoFolder SubFolder.Path   '<---Here.
Next
```

...and you don't need to loop through all the files here (you may be overthinking this one a bit):

```
For Each File In folder.Files
  Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  ' Operate on each file
  ActiveDocument.Save
Next
```

Also, I'd suggest using early binding instead of late binding (although the example below can easily be switched).  I'd do something a bit more like this:

```
Private Sub SaveDocToAllSubfolders(targetPath As String, doc As Document, _
                                   Optional root As Boolean = False)
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim current As Scripting.folder
        Set current = .GetFolder(targetPath)
        If Not root Then
            doc.SaveAs .BuildPath(targetPath, doc.Name)
        End If
        Dim subDir As Scripting.folder
        For Each subDir In current.SubFolders
            SaveDocToAllSubfolders subDir.Path, doc
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The `root` flag is just whether or not to save a copy in the host folder. Call it like this:

```
SaveDocToAllSubfolders "H:\test2", ActiveDocument, True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i know proper pain in the backside audits haha! When i try and run it using your code it doesn't actually come up am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Tomlawson94 - I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "doesn't actually come up".  It should just put a copy of the `ActiveDocument` in each subfolder. Did you add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime?